# What is the difference between fidyah الفدية and kaffarah الكفارة?

Tags: fiqh, kaffarah, fidyah

Both terms are used to express an expiation or ransom (based on the actual context).
See for example ([2:85](http://legacy.quran.com/2/85)), ([2:184](http://legacy.quran.com/2/184)) (in context of fast), ([2:196](http://legacy.quran.com/2/196)) (in context of hajj), ([2:229](http://legacy.quran.com/2/229)), ([3:91](http://legacy.quran.com/3/91)), ([5:36](http://legacy.quran.com/5/36)), ([13:18](http://legacy.quran.com/13/18)), ([37:17](http://legacy.quran.com/37/107)), ([47:4](http://legacy.quran.com/47/4)), ([57:15](http://legacy.quran.com/57/15)) and ([7:11](http://legacy.quran.com/70/11)) where the qur'an quotes the term الفدية fidyah (in cases meaning both).

My question is what is the distinction between both Terms?

Comment: Fidyah is expiation for the old and terminally sick people who cannot fast and Kaffarah is for those who broke their fast or don't fast for no valid reason.

Comment: @Armaan no that's why i rejected the tag wiki fidyah and kafarah are also at least issues in hajj, so they are not restricted on sawm/fasting.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

**Fidyah** is something which is paid/done because of leaving/missing some Religious Duty because of some sickness or disability.

While **Kaffarah** is something paid/done because a person leave/miss some religious duty willingly and by his own consent.

**Imam Badr ud Deen Zarkashi**  said in his book **Al Mansoor**:

> أَنَّ الْكَفَّارَةَ لَا تَجِبُ إلَّا عَنْ ذَنْبٍ تَقَدَّمَ، بِخِلَافِهِ الْفِدْيَةُ
>
> وَالْفِدْيَةُ تَدْخُلُ فِي الصَّوْمِ لِلْعَاجِزِ عَنْهُ بِالْهَرَمِ وَالْمَرَضِ

Translation: Kaffarah is not imposed unless someone commit a sin,  opposite to Fidyah.
And Fidayah is imposed for (not) fasting by a person because of inability and sickness.

**Reference**
Al Mansoor: Book # 3, Page # 21
Published in Kuwait

Comment: Please provide examples from the quran and sunnah why this is the case.